# Workflows - Does ISCHANGED trigger when text field is changed from blank to something?

Tags: workflow

I would have thought that a field changing from blank to some text would trigger this, but it doesn't seem to.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: It should trigger, can you paste the formula you are using here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with any change...

```
If a text field was previously blank, this function returns TRUE when it contains any value.

For number, percent, or currency fields, this function returns TRUE when:  

 - The field was blank and now contains any value

 - The field was zero and now is blank

 - The field was zero and now contains any other value
```

But If you have problem with this you could use `PRIORVALUE` to check this.

Please check this :

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US#TEXT

Comment: Does it make any difference is the record is only just being created. i.e My workflow is set to trigger when "created, and every time it’s edited"? Does ISCHANGED work on a field when the record containing that field is just being saved for the first time?

Comment: "This function returns FALSE when evaluating any field on a newly created record." - from documentation

Comment: I was looking at the docs here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm, where it doesn't say that. Thanks.